# Open a TabSet to a specific Tab

Tags: smartclient

By default the first tab becomes selected when a TabSet is drawn

I'm curious to know if it's possible to instead set the initial tab to be tab at index 2, 3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set TabSet.selectedTab:

> Specifies the index of the initially selected tab.

a sample:

```
isc.TabSet.create({
    ID: "topTabSet",
    tabBarPosition: "top",
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    selectedTab:1,
    tabs: [
        {title: "Blue", icon: "pieces/16/pawn_blue.png", iconSize:16,
         pane: isc.Img.create({autoDraw: false, width: 48, height: 48, src: "pieces/48/pawn_blue.png"})},
        {title: "Green", icon: "pieces/16/pawn_green.png", iconSize:16,
         pane: isc.Img.create({autoDraw: false, width: 48, height: 48, src: "pieces/48/pawn_green.png"})}
    ]
});
```

Comment: I've tried calling selectTab before the tabset is drawn and it still selected the tab at index 0, THEN selects the tab at the specified index

Comment: Note: I didn't mean TabSet.selectTab() method, but selectedTab attribute.